# Eclipse misplaces maven resources in output jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have a maven project loaded in eclipse that when I go to export it as jar, the src/main/resources files always end up in the /resources directory inside the jar. I found a kludge to get around this by putting all my resources in the root directory of the project, but it's getting very messy very fast. Is there any way to configure it so the resources output to root of jar?

Comment: You would need to write your own compiler that moves the resources folder around and put it where you want. This can be done pretty easily using a bash script

Answer (score 0):

you dont export a maven project as jar.
you `clean package` it and you get the resulting jar at the target folder.
right click the project's pom.xml and run it as maven build.